# CSS goes wrong on companies list page

Tags: bug, design, pagination, jobs, company-page

Currently [This Page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies?pg=2) facing some issue with CSS:

[image]

I have tried to open that link in Incognito Window too.

Comment: Which browser did you use? Can neither reproduce with Firefox nor with Chrome.

Comment: I am using Chrome, it is displaying in Incognito Window too.

Comment: Looks like a problem loading the icon font. Nevertheless, works on my side :/ Did you try disabling all (possibly installed) extensions?

Comment: I have installed two extensions only. Grammarly and Fireshot

Comment: Works for me in both Firefox Nightly 76.0a1 and Chrome. Does the console reveal any error about failing to load a resource?

Comment: If It is an error to load resource then it should be offline (downloaded).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, Its problem as below:

Some restricted websites couldn't be loaded so fonts are not loading properly.

[image]

I think that file [**MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf**](https://cdn.sstatic.net/careers/fonts/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf?v=fc05de31234e) should be downloaded so that the problem will overcome for all.

Thank you.

Comment: Why downvote? Its a suggestion for the website.